# Compare a portion of String value present in 2 Lists

Tags: python-2.7, list

Below code extract a particular value from `List` srchlist and check for a  particular value in  List rplzlist. The contents of list srchlist and rplzlist looks like below.

```
srchlist = ["DD='A'\n", "SOUT='*'\n", 'PGM=FTP\n', 'PGM=EMAIL']
rplzlist = ['A=ZZ.VVMSSB\n', 'SOUT=*\n', 'SALEDB=TEST12']
```

I am extracting the characters after the '='(*equal*) sign and  within the single quotes using a combination of `strip` and `translate` function.

Of the elements in the srchlist only the 'SOUT' matches with the rplzlist.

Do let me know why the below code does not work, also suggest me a better approach to compare a part of `string` present in the `list`.

```
for ele in srchlist:
      sYmls = ele.split('=')
      vAlue = sYmls[1].translate(None,'\'')
      for elem in rplzlist:
      rPls = elem.split('=')
      if vAlue in rPls:
          print("vAlue")
```

Comment: It does not work because is comparing '*' (from srchlist) to '*\n' (from rplzlist), therefore it isn't printing any value. You should perform replace '\n' with '' in rPls too.

Comment: change your `print("vALUE")` to `print(vALUE)`. and @EmersonCardoso `'*'\n` is already changed to `*\n` using this: `sYmls[1].translate(None,'\'')`

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo I was refering to the line `rPls = elem.split('=')`; he could change it to `rPls = elem.split('=').replace('\n', '')`.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso alright, I got that, but he may be wanted to use `\n` in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the more pythonic approach for what you wanted to do:

```
>>> list(set([(i.split('='))[1].translate(None,'\'') for i in srchlist]) & set([j.split('=')[1] for j in rplzlist]))
['*\n']
```

I used `set()` and then get the whole output as `list`, you may use `.join()`.
Inside `set()`, list comprehension is given which is **faster** than the normal for loops.

---

Another Solution Using `join()`, and `replace()` in place of `translate()`:

```
>>> "".join(set([(i.split('='))[1].replace('\'','') for i in srchlist]) & set([j.split('=')[1] for j in rplzlist]))
'*\n'
```

Comment: i am fairly new to Python,what is the significance of adding ['*\n'] at the end

Comment: As I took all matching values in `set()`, which gives a list, after that for display of matching set values we can take `list` or provide a `join()` for the desired output display.